# How to fix table header with horizontal scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, css, horizontal-scrolling, tableheader

My table header is having two rows. Number of columns in these rows are not same.
http://jsbin.com/exacey

Now, I would  like to fix the `thead` portion and make the `tbody` scrollable. I tried few jQuery plugins namely: 
https://github.com/farinspace/jquery.tableScroll ; 
https://github.com/benjaminleouzon/tablefixedheader
https://github.com/golovko/Fixed-Header-Table

The thing is, these plugin work great till you want to fix the header provided there is no horizontal scroll.  Infact, https://github.com/benjaminleouzon/tablefixedheader claimed to support horizontal scroll bars, but in my case it failed.

I also tried to manually fix it. I was using this 
http://www.imaputz.com/cssStuff/bigFourVersion.html
But this too is only for vertical scroll.

So, Please help me in fixing the header. Please provide some link that can be useful for me.

Comment: Try doing manually what those plugins do it using javascript.
Make two tables inside table, first one for thead and second one for tbody. Now give height to tbody and set overflow-y to auto. Give width to parent of both these tables and give overflow as auto so both of child tables have same horizontal scrolls.

Answer (score 1):

I see the Fixed header http://www.tablefixedheader.com/fullpagedemo/  works perfectly fine. Can you post your failed code using tablefixedheader plugin ?